# Target an html element based on title tag using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, tags, append, title

How to target an HTML element based on its title tag?

let's say we have:

```
<a class="cat" title="categoryName">categoryName</a>
```

How to target this anchor element using its title tag then append some text to it.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$(".cat['title' = *categoryName*]").append('*someText*');
```

also tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$(".cat['title' ~= *categoryName*]").append('*someText*');
```

Comment: Why have you closed the tag `<a>` prematurely?

Comment: My bad, sorry about that

Comment: are you looking for exact match or title containing the text `categoryName`?

Comment: How about `$('.cat[title = "categoryName"]').append('*someText*');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>2</s>1 problem<s>s</s>:

- <s>You've got an invalid `a` tag - you've prematurely closed it, and</s>
- your selector is wrong. See the [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) section at the jQuery docs.

This works:

```js
$(".cat[title = 'categoryName']").append('someText');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="cat" title="categoryName">categoryName</a>
```